# Xcode Swift, Geo Location won't show where i am

Tags: swift, xcode

any one understand why Geo location won't show me where i am, also the permissions don't work over..... I'm baffled... laptop location is fine, also the app permissions are also set, also the Allow permissions tap, box for the user won't appear either

(iv explained this all above and it won't post unless i type more stuff in the box, but could some one explain why this code doesn't work norrr does it display no errors at all, i had also checked - DEBUG - locations... still nothing

```
  import UIKit
  import MapKit
  import CoreLocation

  class MapScreen: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let regionInMeters: Double = 10000

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        checkLocationServices()
    }


    func setupLocationManager() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    }


    func centerViewOnUserLocation() {
        if let location = locationManager.location?.coordinate {
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: location, latitudinalMeters: regionInMeters, longitudinalMeters: regionInMeters)
            mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        }
    }


    func checkLocationServices() {
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            setupLocationManager()
            checkLocationAuthorization()
        } else {
            // Show alert letting the user know they have to turn this on.
        }
    }


    func checkLocationAuthorization() {
        switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            mapView.showsUserLocation = true
            centerViewOnUserLocation()
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            break
        case .denied:
            // Show alert instructing them how to turn on permissions
            break
        case .notDetermined:
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        case .restricted:
            // Show an alert letting them know what's up
            break
        case .authorizedAlways:
            break
        }
    }
}


extension MapScreen: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.last else { return }
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: location.coordinate, latitudinalMeters: regionInMeters, longitudinalMeters: regionInMeters)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }


    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,       didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        checkLocationAuthorization()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you add the permission strings to your info.plist?

You need to add explanations for these otherwise the permission prompt won't appear, and no location updates will be send to your app.

`NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`

You should also get an error for this in your console so check that as well.